# Changing HTML with Ajax and JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

So I'm trying to make a randomly selected piece of text from a JSON (well it's actually JSONP because of same origin policy issues) file appear in a web app.

I generate a random number like so:

```
function randomNumberCreator(numberOfOptions){
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberOfOptions);
    return randomNumber;
};
```

My JSON code looks like this (this is a sample - it goes on):

```
otmjsonp({

    "option2" : "this text",

    "option3" : "that text",

    "option4" : "some other text",

    });
```

And was hoping to be able to just do something like this:

```
$(".choice1").html(JSON.option+randomNumberCreator(4));
```

But this appears not to work so I've had to come up with an elaborate work around (this is really ridiculous, I know):

```
function updateTree(){

$.ajax({

    url:"http://www.WEBSITE.com/json/newotmtree.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "otmjsonp",
    async: false,   
    success: function(JSON){

    $(".initialChoices a").each(function(){
    $(this).show();
    });

    function rollDice(){
    diceRoll = randomNumberCreator(6);


    switch(diceRoll){
            case 1:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option2)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option3)
            break;

            case 2:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option5)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option6)
            break;

            case 3:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option8)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option9)
            break;

            case 4:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option11)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option1)
            break;

            case 5:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option3)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option4)
            break;

            case 6:
            $(".choice1").html(JSON.option1)
            $(".choice2").html(JSON.option4)
            $(".choice3").html(JSON.option9)
            break;

            default:
            alert("switch fail");

    }
    };

    rollDice();


    var option1 = JSON.option1;
    var option2 = JSON.option2;
    var option3 = JSON.option3;
    var option4 = JSON.option4;
    var option5 = JSON.option5;
    var option6 = JSON.option6;
    var option7 = JSON.option7;
    var option8 = JSON.option8;
    var option9 = JSON.option9;
    var option10 = JSON.option10;
    var option11 = JSON.option11;
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("error");
    }
```

});
};

For completeness, here is the HTML:

```
<ul class="initialChoices">
<li><p><a class = "choice1" href="#">AJAX FAIL</a></p></li>
<li><p><a class = "choice2" class="button" href="#">AJAX FAIL</a></p></li>                           
<li><p><a class = "choice3" class="button" href="#">AJAX FAIL</a></p></li>                    
</ul>
```

Is there a way for me to make my JSONP response truly random (like what I was hoping to do) - or am I stuck with this ugly solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For random values, you'll find it much easier to use an array.  Since you're not using the property names from your JSON object, you can fill an array with just the values.  Picking a random value from the array is as simple as `a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]`:

```
$.ajax({

    url:"http://www.WEBSITE.com/json/newotmtree.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "otmjsonp",
    async: false,
    success: function(JSON){

      var a=[],i;
      for(i in JSON)a.push(JSON[i]);

      $(".initialChoices a").each(function(){
        $(this).html(a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)]);
        $(this).show();
      });

    },
    error:function(){
    alert("error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct way is

```
$(".choice1").html(JSON["option"+randomNumberCreator(4)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$(".choice1").html(JSON["option" + randomNumberCreator(4)]);
```

might work